# Handling lines from text files

Tags: python-3.x, text-files

There is something that I am fundamentally misunderstanding. Relatively new to Python in general, I would really appreciate it if I could be aimed in the right direction as to where I go for a better understanding.

This is the configuration file that another program I am working with reads, and appends to.

```
Color=blue
Start Date=10/01/2017
End Date=01/01/2018
01/01/2017 This is what happened on this date.
04/01/2017 This is what happened on this date.
07/01/2017 This is what happened on this date.
10/01/2017 This is what happened on this date.
01/01/2018 This is what happened on this date.
```

My goal is to simply replace line 2 and 3 with newer dates so that the next time this configuration is read, it will produce a quarterly report with the proper Start & End dates. This is then automatically emailed to a few execs.

I have no problem doing the date math and generating what goes into the two strings, so I've eliminated that from here for brevity's sake.

This is the example that I wrote to exemplify what is wrong.

```
#--------------------------------------------------
import os
import sys

Line2 = 'Start Date=01/01/2018'
Line3 = 'End Date=04/01/2018'

ResultFile = open('C:/Apps/newconfig.txt','w')

try:
    f = open('C:/Apps/config.txt','r')
    for line in f:
        if line[0:5] == 'Start':
            print(Line2, file=ResultFile)
        elif line[0:5] == 'End D':
            print(Line3, file=ResultFile)
        else:
            print(line, file=ResultFile)
    f.close()

except:
    print('fail', file=ResultFile)

ResultFile.close()
#--------------------------------------------------
```

What I do not understand is why the code:

```
        print(line, file=ResultFile)
```

Writes this to ResultFile:

```
('Color=blue\n')
```

**Why are the parenthesis, single quotes, and the newline here?**

Yet, when I choose to assign it to a variable using a slice, I only had to deal with the newline. I've gotten around it by using the following:

```
    ConfigFileLen = len(line)
    ConfigFileLine = line[0:ConfigFileLen-1]
```

and

```
    print(ConfigFileLine, file=ResultFile)
```

But that just seems awkward, so I thought I'd ask.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. However, rather than use 'print', which will add an extra newline character, use `ResultFile.write(line)`, which will print the original line.

Comment: Also, if `line` is of length 1, you can access that value with `line[0]` - you don't need to slice (i.e. don't need to use `:`). Hope that helps. Welcome to python! :)

Comment: I added newlines to Line2 & Line3 and I am good to go. Much cleaner. 
It ain't easy being green. Thanks!